# Check if a value exists in pandas dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am sure there is an obvious way to do this but cant think of anything slick right now.

Basically instead of raising exception I would like to get `True` or `False` to see if a value exists in pandas `df` index.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':[1,2,3,4]}, index=['a','b','c','d'])
df.loc['g']  # (should give False)
```

What I have working now is the following

```
sum(df.index == 'g')
```

Comment: What about any(df.index == 'g') ?

Answer (score 372, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
'g' in df.index
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when several entries share the same index values.

Comment: @MaximG What do you mean? This works for a non-unique index as well.

Comment: Also work for multi index. If your index has length `n`, then a tuple of any length from `1..n` can be checked

Comment: For others coming here, you may need to use `'g' in df.columns` if your dataframe was defined with column headings rather than an index, e.g.: `df = pandas.DataFrame({'test':[1,2,3,4]}, columns=['a','b','c','d'])`

Comment: Is this constant time or linear?

Comment: This also works for multiindex. `idx = pd.IndexSlice; idx['foo','bar'] in df.index`

Comment: `in` operator works for `pd.Series` if used with `keys()` (which returns an Index): `'foo' in row.keys()  # where row is pd.Series`

Answer (score 50):

Multi index works a little different from single index.  Here are some methods for multi-indexed dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b','c', 'd'], 'col2': ['X','X','Y', 'Y'], 'col3': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])
```

`in df.index` works for the first level only when checking single index value.

```
'a' in df.index     # True
'X' in df.index     # False
```

Check `df.index.levels` for other levels.

```
'a' in df.index.levels[0] # True
'X' in df.index.levels[1] # True
```

Check in `df.index` for an index combination tuple.

```
('a', 'X') in df.index  # True
('a', 'Y') in df.index  # False
```

Answer (score 45):

Just for reference as it was something I was looking for, you can test for presence within the values or the index by appending the ".values" method, e.g.

```
g in df.<your selected field>.values
g in df.index.values
```

I find that adding the ".values" to get a simple list or ndarray out makes exist or "in" checks run more smoothly with the other python tools. Just thought I'd toss that out there for people.

Comment: but AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'field'

Comment: Hi Gank. The "field" was supposed to show you can apply the ".values" method to various fields of the dataframe such as columns or a selected column. ".index" is an example of replacing "field" with an actual field that is available :) I guess that could be clearer...

Comment: This was really helpful to point out. I have a hierarchical case where `in g in df.index` produces true and `in g in df.index.values` false. Interesting.

Comment: @watsonic - one caution point there is to see if one of those is returning tuples due to hierarchy.  Make sure to look what both are putting out (e.g. in ipython or command line) to make sure you understand what you're comparing to. Another thing you can do with hierarchical indexes is df.index.get_level_values(<level name>) to make things more understandable - depending on your application of course.

Comment: This will increase lookup time considerably, because instead of using the pandas optimized search indexer you are traversing a list. Apologies for formatting,

```python
data = [{'a': random.random(), 'b': random.randint(0, 10), 'c': i} for i in range(10000)]
data2 = [{'a': random.random(), 'b': random.randint(0, 10), 'c': i} for i in range(100)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data2)
timeit 99999 in df2.index  # 442ns
timeit 99999 in df1.index  # 476ns
timeit 99999 in df2.index.values  # 3310ns
timeit 99999 in df1.index.values  # 63900ns
```

Answer (score 4):

Code below does not print boolean, but allows for dataframe subsetting by index... I understand this is likely not the most efficient way to solve the problem, but I (1) like the way this reads and (2) you can easily subset where df1 index exists in df2:

```
df3 = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

or where df1 index does not exist in df2...

```
df3 = df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

Answer (score 2):

with DataFrame: df_data

```
>>> df_data
  id   name  value
0  a  ampha      1
1  b   beta      2
2  c     ce      3
```

I tried:

```py
>>> getattr(df_data, 'value').isin([1]).any()
True
>>> getattr(df_data, 'value').isin(['1']).any()
True
```

but:

```py
>>> 1 in getattr(df_data, 'value')
True
>>> '1' in getattr(df_data, 'value')
False
```

So fun :D

Comment: `isin` won't check for the dtype. `df['value'].isin([True]).any()` try this, it will also gives you True, Because it matches with `1`. `True -> 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'g':[1]}, index=['isStop'])

#df.loc['g']

if 'g' in df.index:
    print("find g")

if 'isStop' in df.index:
    print("find a")
```

Comment: What is isStop?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use:

```py
if 'value' in df.index.get_level_values(0):
    print(True)
```

**get_level_values** method is good because it allows you to get the value in the indexes no matter if your index is simple or composite.

Use 0 (zero) if you have a single index in your dataframe [*or you want to check the first index in multiple index levels*]. Use 1 for the second index, and so on...