# Check if set of elements in pandas index

Tags: python, pandas

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549231/check-if-a-value-exists-in-pandas-dataframe-index),

```
'g' in df.index
```

is *the* way to check whether 'g' is in my index. What if I want to do that for many elements? Say, I have an iterable object `myIterable` (np.ndarray, list), and I want to get the elements that are in or not in my index...

```
inIterable = [x for x in myIterable if x in df.index]
notInIterable = [x for x in myIterable if x not in df.index]
```

will work, but is quite inefficient. What is the most efficient way of creating `in` and `notIn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, If I understand correctly to test for membership you can use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
In [132]:

l=[1,2,7]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4]})
df.index.intersection(l)
Out[132]:
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

For the reverse one method would be to construct a pandas index and use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
In [137]:

pd.Index(l).difference(df.index)
Out[137]:
Int64Index([7], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want - or at least I cant see how to use it. Say your iterable was `l=[1,2,3]`. Now, `3` is an element that is not in the index. That is, `notIn = [3]`. How would I get `notIn`?

Comment: So you just want to test membership rather than to mask correct?

Comment: Hmm, I couldnt find a `index.complements()` method. So, to get `notIn`, I would first need to `in = df.index.intersection(l)` and then `notIn = set(l) - set(in)`? Sounds arbitrary that it would support intersection but not complements.

Comment: Ah, its not complements, its difference :D

Comment: You can use `difference` but you'd need to construct an index object

Comment: Might want to just use set instead of making an Index object. `set(l).difference(df.index)`
And if you just want to test that all are in index: `set(l).issubset(df.index)`

Answer (score 1):

Use filter:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]    # Index
b = [99,2,99,5]    # MyIterable

in = filter(lambda x: x in a, b)
```

Note: your example should be:

```
in = [x for x in myIterable if x in df.index]
```

And "in" is a reserved word.