# Python panda dataframe Assign NaN if couldn't locate index

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading values thorough index and column name. I want to assign NaN value if given index or column name is not present in data frame.

```
ktm_bc = emiss.loc['Ktm']['CO']
```

Here 'emiss' is an dataframe. 
I am trying to assign NaN value to ktm_bc if index 'ktm' or 'CO' is not present in dataframe.

```
ktm_all_bc = [ ]

for i in range(10):

 emiss=pd.read_excel('emission_data_for_py.xlsx',sectors[i],header=1,index_col=0)
 ktm_bc = emiss.loc['Ktm']['CO']
 ktm_all_bc = ktm_all_bc.append(ktm_bc)
```

It is showing value error, if ['Ktm'] or ['CO'] are not present in 'emiss'
So, i want to assign NaN value, when index or column name not found, to continue the loop.

Comment: you have an errors in the code: For example `emiss.loc['Ktm']['CO']` or `ktm_all_bc.append(ktm_bc)`

Comment: The error is in `emiss.loc['Ktm']['CO']`,  `'ktm'` index is not present in emiss. So, instead of showing error, can it assign NaN value to `ktm_bc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
ktm_bc  = np.nan
if 'Ktm' in emiss.index:
    ktm_bc = emiss.loc['Ktm']
```

The same code for the other index. See also [hier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549231/check-if-a-value-exists-in-pandas-dataframe-index).

Comment: I am looking for same answer, thank you. Here I have used your suggestion for index and column name both.

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestion can be used for index and columns simultaneously using 'and'

`ktm_bc = np.nan
        if 'Ktm' in emiss.index and 'CO' in emiss.columns:
                ktm_bc = emiss.loc['Ktm']['CO']`