# Check if an Index is in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549231/check-if-a-value-exists-in-pandas-dataframe-index) states that to check if there is an entry in a DataFrame with a certain index, one can write a conditional:

```
if 'index' in df.index:
    print(True)
```

In my case, something odd is happening: I am running a test over a DataFrame of Stock information pulled from the pyEX API/package, checking if a series of dates are in df.index, such as:

```
for i in ['2021-11-18', '2021-04-19', '2021-06-20', '2021-05-10']:
    if i in df.index:
       print(i + "is an index")
```

The problem is that this is evaluating as True even for dates that are not printed on the DataFrame. Not sure how this is possible. So when run against:

```
              close    volume
date                         
2021-11-17  1092.85  31696364
2021-11-16  1071.54  26740198
2021-11-15  1037.27  35725807
```

all of the above dates from my for loop are still being evaluated as in the index. How could this be?

Comment: are you sure those dates aren't in your df? what happens when you `df.loc['2021-11-18']`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the same output with your example . It doesn't print anything. The result of `any((date in df.index) for date in ['2021-11-18', '2021-04-19', '2021-06-20', '2021-05-10'])` is False. 
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your error. The following only prints the last date, which I've added and is in the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"""
date,close,volume        
2021-11-17,1092.85,31696364
2021-11-16,1071.54,26740198
2021-11-15,1037.27,35725807
"""
)).set_index('date')

for i in ['2021-11-18', '2021-04-19', '2021-06-20', '2021-05-10','2021-11-15']:
    if i in df.index:
       print(i + " is an index")
```